# Probability of all trial success in infinite Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve a homework problem, and I am stuck in the following question:
What is the probability of all trials to be successful in an infinite sequence of independent Bernoulli trials?  The probability of success is given by p and of failure is (1-p). I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** The probability of $n$ successes in a row is $p^n.$ What happens as $n\to\infty$? What if $p=1$? What if $p<1?$